# How to copy the "Local Items" Keychain to a new mac?

Tags: mac, keychain, macos

I copied my whole HDD from MBPOld to MBPNew, but saw the "Local Objects" Keychain is empty.

I then saw there is a folder in `~/Library/Keychains` named like the UUID of the Mac. (which can be retrieved with `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep 'Hardware UUID' | awk '{print $3}'`).

I restarted the Mac in recovery mode (by holding down <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and opened up Terminal to rename the folder from OldMBP-UUID to NewMBP-UUID but still the local objects keychain is empty.

Is there any way to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: I just managed to get my keys to my new mac (this only works if you still have access to the old Mac and can boot it up):

- (on the old mac) Remove your current user's password
- Create a new keychain (without a password)
- Copy all keys in "Local Items" to your new keychain
- Copy the keychain to the new mac
- (on the new mac) Remove your current user's password
- Add the new keychain file
- Copy all keys in the new keychain to "Local Items"
- Delete the new keychain
- Don't forget to set a password again after that

It's a bit annoying as you have to click "Allow" for EACH item in the keychain but well, it's the only thing I found that works.